# What regulations apply to changing liveries on private jets in the US?

Tags: faa-regulations, private-jets, livery

Things like the manufacturer's livery, do they need to follow that?

Anything else that will be required when purchasing a new jet and changing the paint to the new owner's choice and requirements.

Comment: Usually requires a new weight and balance. There are a number of regulations, are you asking about them regarding style? Application and removal? Colors?

Comment: Yes, if it does not conform to the manufacturer's original requirements. No, to the removal and application or colour. The point you make about the weight and balance, I'm sure is something new owners do not immediately consider.

Comment: I do understand that having a new colour that's very dark, can also be what changes a planes weight and balance, maintenance (oil streaks are not as obvious), cost to apply and resell value could take a hit.

Answer (score 1):

The only requirement is the height of the registration number, 12" if flying internationally (from the US anyway), 2" I think if staying domestic, and maybe new weight & balance - but usually a layer of paint and primer is taken off, and a new layer is put on, so the weight change is minimal.  Any control surfaces that were removed may need rebalancing.  Colors & schemes are at the whim of the owner(s).